# color body set to auto change margin

Tags: html, css

Here's my style sheet.

I'm trying to get the margin around my body to have a different color from the body itself. Here's my beginning code.  Is a reset section really necessary?  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong...

```
@charset "utf-8";
html {
    color: #d9a552;
}

body {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    background: white ;
    width:  960px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1050px;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:  I added section tag immediately following the body tag.  I gave it a class id of 'mainBody'.  Then I adjusted the code as follows:

I know I can't give myself credit, but I thought I would share my solution for someone else to use.  I will give both you guys credit for steering me in the right direction.
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a border. If you want to make the margin around your body red, simply use this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 10px solid red;
    /*and this is to make it stretch all the way*/
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {height:100%;}
```

as can be seen in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cXC22/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding padding-top: 20px; to the html instead of margin-top: 20px; with the body:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
html {  
padding-top: 20px;
background: #d9a552;
}

body {
display: table;
margin: auto;
background: white;
width:  960px;
max-width: 1050px;
height: 100%;
font-weight: 300;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

I believe you also want to change color: #d9a552; to

```
background: #d9a552;
```

or

```
background-color: #d9a552;
```

Comment: The `html` element is not really meant to be styled. If you want to design your webpage, you should use `div`s instead of doing it the easy way and applying your styles to the `html` element.

Comment: Ultimately, Joeytje50 is correct -- a wrapper div that was 100% the size of the body would be more ideal, but you will see some people make use of the html element depending upon needs.

Comment: Here's what I got to work:
    <body { border-right: 200px solid #d9a552; border-left; 200px         solid #d9a552;>
The problem with that is that if I expand the window the white part returns.